# NodeJS - extract only the first part of an absolute path using regex (closed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Say we have a file path like the following...

```
This/is/my/path/to/file.txt
```

How would I get the first part of this file path and then get rid of the rest of the path, so I'm left with an output like below?

```
This/
```

I've managed to construct the following regex below...

```js
var file = "this/is/my/path/to/file.txt"

var regex = file.match(/\/(.+?)\//)[1]
var str = file;
var output = str.match(regex);

console.log(output);
```

but it's not doing what I want, it's only returning the second part of the file path wrapped in square brackets as shown below...

```
[
 "is"
]
```

I am very new to Regex in JavaScript so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I've tried on this for about 4 hours, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing one match and with the result you are doing a second match, I don't really understand, but in my solution there is just a regex to match anything except a slash plus one slash (that gives `This/`, just like in your example)

```js
var file = "This/is/my/path/to/file.txt";

var regex = /[^/]+\//;
var [output] = file.match(regex);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: also you could do `var output = file.split("/")[0]` to get `This` but you asked for regex

Comment: [here](https://regexr.com/6s97q) is the regex with tests btw

Comment: Thanks guys so much for your help and for the swift replies, this is one of the reasons I Love SO.

Comment: actually the answer and the comments was all me but thanks @Morsmalleo :)

Comment: Let me explain why this needs to be done a bit more, so basically I have an application built with nodeJS, where the `file` string would need to be join up with another path, say for instance a `folder` path for one function... then for a second function... we need to obtain only the first part of the `file` path and drop the results into a seperate variable called `filePathFirstFolder`, so we can join paths up again and stick some files in the first folder instance of `file` by use of `(folder + filePathFirstFolder)` if any of that makes sense

Comment: Oh well in that case, thank you so much sir ♥️

Comment: also @Morsmalleo you can close the question now